# How to get the current project name in php code?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, path

I'm new to php. I want to use function get project name but i don't know how.
Example:

> F:\VertrigoServ\www\first_wordpress...

project name is "first_wordpress".

Pleas help me.

Thanks! Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please always keep your questions a bit descriptive.

Answer (score -1):

This is hard to get because of some reasons:

- Project name may change
- Path may be different in your local system or in your web server, so you cant substring your path

What I suggest is to have a config file with some values that are constant in your project and that are going to stay always the same, like your project name.

I would create this:

constants.php

```
<?php

const PROJECT_NAME = 'first_wordpress';
const SOME_OTHER_CONST = 'whatever';
const FOO = 'bar';

?>
```

and then include it in the file you need it, for example

index.php

```
include 'constants.php';
echo 'This is my project name '.PROJECT_NAME;
```

I guess that you are using Wordpress, so your constant file, or config, is called wp-config.php. Try that!

**Edit**: 
a user of php.net brings [this solution](http://php.net/manual/es/function.dirname.php#70709).

I hope it helps!